# Multiple redirects for the same host only differentiated by URL parameters

Tags: url, redirect, dns, hosting, namecheap

I am trying to achieve this:

Case 1: User accesses `foo.com` -> will be redirected to `somedomain.com/someinfo`

Case 2: User accesses `foo.com/u/${username}` -> will be redirected to `otherdomain.com/u/${username}`

I have Namecheap and I can set URL Redirect Record for the second case (mind that username is always changed in the URL, therefore the syntax, imagine some public profile underneath). Is it even possible to add some DNS records to accommodate just for accessing the `foo.com` visit?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I've used a Lambda function on AWS to do the functionality.